# R: which() with vector in condition

Tags: r

I have data

```
test <- 1:10
```

and I would like to obtain the indices of `test` that fulfill different related conditions. For example,

```
which(test>5)[1] 
which(test>8)[1]
which(test>9)[1]
```

yield

```
[1]  6  
[1]  9 
[1]  10
```

when carried out individually, but is there a way to execute them simultaneously using a vector like

```
bounds <- c(5,8,9)
```

That then yields a vector containing the indices for each value in `bounds`?

Comment: One option is `sapply(bounds, function(x) which(test > x)[1])#[1]  6  9 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options are

```
findInterval(bounds, test) + 1
#[1]  6  9 10
```

which is the fastest, or

```
max.col(outer(bounds, test, `<`), 'first')
#[1]  6  9 10
```

which is the slowest, along with the commented one below the OP's post:

```
sapply(bounds, function(x) which(test > x)[1])
#[1] 6 9 10
```

which is neither the fastest, nor the slowest.

Comment: Thanks — it turns out, `findInterval()` is the fastest and `max.col()` takes about 1000 times as long. `sapply()` about 100 times. Cheers! Can you add the latter to the answer?

Comment: @bumblebee If you have the benchmarks on big data, please go ahead and edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use apply:

`sapply(bounds, function(x) which(test>x)[1])
[1]  6  9 10`